# What product does "EDN ArcGIS Enterprise Advanced" key unlock?

Tags: arcgis-platform, edn, license

I have a key to unlock something called "EDN ArcGIS Enterprise Advanced"   I tried to unlock ArcEditor with the key - seemed like the obvious choice, but that didn't work.  The key starts with first three letters "ECP".  It seems like it unlocks a Server, but I thought the server license cost $30K and I don't think we paid for that license, but it is available to me in the EDN portal customers.esri.com

Comment: If you paid for the EDN plus Arceditor, I think you'd get a separate license for arceditor. Pricing is [here](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/edn/pricing.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is an EDN license that allows you to use the full ArcGIS Server product. See [here](http://www.esri.com/library/brochures/pdfs/arcgis-server-functionality-matrix.pdf) for the differences between the Basic, Standard, and Advanced versions.

You probably didn't pay $30k for it; it just came with your EDN subscription to allow you to develop against an enterprise version of the software.

Answer (score 2):

ArcGIS Server. The ["Enterprise Advanced" refers to the edition/capabilities](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisserver/key-functionality.html).